# <button> with form attribute does not work on IE

Tags: html, forms, button, input, action

my question is why something like that:

```
<form id="aaa" action"xxx">
</form>
<button form="aaa" type="submit">Button</button>
```

does work in Firefox,Opera,Chrome and does NOT work in IE 11 and mobile devices with Windows system? Example above does nothing, button seems not to belongs to form.

thank You in advance.

Comment: the button tag needs to be inside the form tag if you want it to submit the form

Comment: The button's `form` attribute is an HTML5 thing... do you (@user3152194) know if IE 11 supports it?  My guess is no.

Comment: What is your reason for not putting the button inside the form?

Comment: lets say I have 2 forms with two diffrent actions and some input fields with REQUIRED attribute. i cant put form into a form and dont want to make one button click affect on input fields which are not belong to form of clicked button.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the button should ideally be within the form. However, one way to proceed, with the button outside of the form, is to have the button trigger the form submit via JavaScript.

A quick and dirty jQuery example to illustrate:

```
$('button[form="aaa"]').click(function()
{
    $('#aaa').submit();
});
```

You can replace this with an in-line onclick="" attribute on the button element if preferred.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but I thought I'd share how I got this working with a React app. I needed the `onSubmit` callbacks to be run when a `form` was submitted, and that wasn't happening when calling `submit` directly on the form. Here was my quick solution to the problem. It only accounts for buttons outside of the form:

```
/**
 * Is the [form] attribute supported?
 */
const isSupported = (() => {
  const TEST_FORM_NAME = 'form-attribute-polyfill-test';
  const testForm = document.createElement('form');
  testForm.setAttribute('id', TEST_FORM_NAME);
  testForm.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  const testInput = document.createElement('input');
  testInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  testInput.setAttribute('form', TEST_FORM_NAME);
  testForm.appendChild(testInput);
  document.body.appendChild(testInput);
  document.body.appendChild(testForm);
  const sampleElementFound = testForm.elements.length === 1;
  document.body.removeChild(testInput);
  document.body.removeChild(testForm);
  return sampleElementFound;
})();

/**
 * If it's not, listen for clicks on buttons with a form attribute.
 * In order to submit the form and have all the callbacks run, we insert
 * a button, click it and then remove it to simulate a submission from
 * inside the form.
 */
if (!isSupported) {
  window.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const {target} = e;
    const formId = target.getAttribute('form');
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'button' && formId) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const form = document.getElementById(formId);
      const button = document.createElement('button');
      form.appendChild(button);
      button.click();
      form.removeChild(button);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `submit` button is generally used to submit data from a form to the server (JavaScript not taken into account). As the button in your example is not part of the form, it has no associated data to submit.

EDIT: After noticing the `form` attribute, the user JayC's answer is correct. Internet Explorer does not support that attribute on buttons, whereas the other browsers do. Its a part of the HTML 5 standards which has not been implemented yet.

Comment: then how to make something like that works :
    <input type="text" form="a1" required>
    <button type="submit" form="a2">
    <input type="text" form="a2" required>
    <button type="submit" form="a1">

i wish to click on second button to pass parameter from first input and dont to make "require clouds" to apper from diffrent form?

Comment: Multiple forms (not embedded into each other) or JavaScript will be needed to do anything other than basic "submit the data from this form". You either need to redesign the forms, making them both completely separate, or you will need to use JavaScript to override the default behaviour.